# Need SearchBar to give same result even if its capital letters or not

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, searchbar

I need SearchBar to give same result even if its capital letters or not.

This is the code I use to filter:

```
myList.ItemsSource = wasteList.Where(x => x.WasteType.Contains(e.NewTextValue));
```

I have also tried following but the results from SearchBar are still different:

```
myList.ItemsSource = wasteList.Where(x => x.WasteType.ToLower.Contains(e.NewTextValue));
myList.ItemsSource = wasteList.Where(x => x.WasteType.ToUpper.Contains(e.NewTextValue));
```

Please, does anyone not to make the SearchBar none case sensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make both of the values ToLower (or ToUpper) and then compare them:

```
myList.ItemsSource = wasteList.Where(x => x.WasteType.ToLower.Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower));
```

Comment: Calling `ToLower` on both `string`s will cause unnecessary allocations that could be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`CompareInfo Class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) of `System.Globalization` with [`CompareOptions.IgnoreCase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) for case insensitive comparison?

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
myList.ItemsSource = wasteList.Where(x => culture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(x, e.NewTextValue, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the `SearchBar` has nothing to do with case sensitivity it simply gives you the UI and Bindings/events to be able to handle the filtering yourself. What you need to do is perform a case insensitive `string` comparison when filtering your list.

A nice approach would be to use something like this extension method:

```
public static bool Contains(this string source, string value, StringComparison comparison)
{
    return source?.IndexOf(value, comparison) >= 0;
}
```

Then to use it you simply need to use:

```
myList.ItemsSource = wasteList.Where(x => x.WasteType.Contains(e.NewTextValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```